# Firebase notifications limit iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to send notifications from the firebase console to different (TestFlight) devices, but there is a max of <1000 (limit) in the firebase console. On the moment I don't have real users (only test users), but hopefully it will come when I place it in the App Store. When I've more than 1000 users, not all users will receive a notification.

[image]

I read the docs of firebase and tried already to add topics to my code, but I can't test it (need more than 1000 users).
Please could someone give me a help on how is it possible to send more than 1000 notifications by using the firebase console?

Comment: "is it possible to send more than 1000 notifications by using the firebase console?" Yes, you can send notifications to any number of users through either topics or audiences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Allright, I added one topic to my code. Is that enough to send more than 1000 notifications?

Comment: There is no limit on how many devices can subscribe to a topic. I recommend continuing implementing the feature and reporting back if you have a problem.